# How to Import/Export Mobile Hub project from one AWS account to other AWS account?

Tags: transfer, aws-mobilehub

I have created Mobile Hub project in one account. But now client want to to transfer all things to different AWS account.

So i have to move my Mobile Hub project to new AWS account.

Please guide me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project. MobileHub supports most case with import/export in same account. But it doesn't support cross account import for push notification and sign-in with 3rd party provider credentials. You also have to manually import AWS Lambda function.